# Firefox URL not working using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, url

The following is basically what i did. It is exactly what the example said but it does not go to the URL when I run it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace TestApp.Selenium_Basics
{
    class TestExercise01
    {
        public void TestExercise01Run()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            driver.Url = @"http://www.facebook.com";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line below *will not* work:

```
driver.Url = @"http://www.facebook.com";
```

Try this instead:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"http://www.facebook.com");
```

Comment: It did not work. Same results. Just opened FireFox and then nothing happens.

Comment: You are missing something then.  The code you have posted above will not do anything.  You have to instruct your browser object to `Navigate()` then, `GoToUrl` for it to work correctly.  Also, are you using a `Console App` to run this?  I don't see any reference to `NUnit` which is what is needed to run a class library project without some kind of front-end.  As I said previously, I think you are missing something.  Post the URL to the tutorial you are using and I will see if I can help you further.

Comment: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-c-sharp/ ...

The thing is it works fine when I use chrome instead. I had to donwload the chrome driver and point it to the location though. So instead I have decided to the course in tutorial in Chrome. Just for learning purposes.